# Why does stereographic projection from the sphere to the plane exclude the projection point?

Tags: geometry, stereographic-projections

> In geometry, the stereographic projection is a particular mapping (function) that projects a sphere onto a plane. The projection is defined on the entire sphere, except at one point: the projection point. Where it is defined, the mapping is smooth and bijective. It is conformal, meaning that it preserves angles at which curves meet. It is neither isometric nor area-preserving: that is, it preserves neither distances nor the areas of figures.

The north pole should correspond to the point at infinity.  The plane is infinite, so the North Pole should not be excluded?

[orthogonal projection](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection)

Comment: This would be a better question if you gave some indication of what you thought the projection should do with the projection point. (Yes, I see your comment under the answer. What I'm saying is that this should have been in the question in the first place so people knew what thought you had given to the question already.)

Answer (score 0):

Because you want to avoid situation in which 2 points from the sphere are mapped onto the same point on the plane. See the example [image](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StereographicProjection.html).

In this case $S$ and $N$ would map to the same point on the plane.

Comment: S has been projected at the origin, and N obviously will not project to the origin, but should be projected to infinity.

Comment: I think you should continue reading the "Definition" section on Wikipedia. The relevant bit: "For any point P on M, there is a unique line through N and P, and this line intersects the plane z = 0 in exactly one point P′. Define the stereographic projection of P to be this point P′ in the plane." Note that in the case of projection point the projective line is not uniquely defined - hence we exclude the projection point for the simplicity of construction.

Comment: @netF: "infinity" is not a point on the plane (just like $\infty$ is not on the number line), although one can define an "extended plane" to include a "pt at infinity"; see ["one-pt compactification"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension). The topology of planes and spheres differs, so whether the pt-at-infinity is desired depends upon context. Besides, it can be more convenient (eg, in the study of conics) to admit a *line* at infinity; this converts the plane into a topological surface known as the ["real projective plane"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_projective_plane).